# how to refresh jquery mobile phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to develop a mobile app with phonegap but I have a problem.

```
    function onBodyLoad(){


$('#contentdining').load('http://localhost/m/contentdining.php',
{reloadPage:true});

var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
var product = serviceURL+'contentproduct.php?id='+id;
$('#contentproduct').load(product,{reloadPage:true});

});
```

In index.html, my problem is "**can not refresh**"

Comment: i'm use 1 page ( index.html ) and use # .load javascript for load php

Comment: i m not sure whether `reloadPage` is valid attribute for `load()`. Besides that do you expect the above script to reload the page twice??

Comment: @dhaval The code is "reloading" two separate pages at once.

Answer (score 1):

The `reloadPage` option is not valid for the `.load()` function, it's for the `$.mobile.changePage()` function:

```
$.mobile.changePage('some-url.html', {
    reloadPage : true
});
```

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Be aware that this only works for external pages. So if your app has all the pseudo-pages in one HTML file you can't use this feature. You can however if you just pull the pseudo-page out of the single HTML document and making one of it's own.

Otherwise you can use `.load()` to reload a page but make sure that the HTML returned from the server creates a valid jQuery Mobile page structure:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the documentation for `.load()`: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Notice that the way you're using `.load()` you are passing a data object so the URL you're loading receives a GET variable named `reloadPage` set to `true`. So to make your page work with `.load()`, simply remove the `{ reloadPage : true }`.

You could be having issues with caching, in which case I recommend using `$.ajax()` so you can specify to not allow cached content:

```
$.ajax({
    url     : serviceURL + 'contentproduct.php?id=' + getUrlVars()["id"],
    type    : 'get',
    cache   : false,
    success : function (response) {
        $('#contentproduct').html(response);
    },
    error   : function (a, b, c) { console.log(b); }
});
```

Setting `cache : false` places a time-stamp on the end of the AJAX request's URL so a new version is grabbed each time.

Comment: hi..jasper..thanks for your answer..your other way ( your code ) working for me..but still can not get "id" . actually my problem i need get parameter from url ( $_GET['id'] ) and use in contentproduct.php . Thanks

Comment: notes : my code work also ..but need click "refresh" manually in my browser ...i need auto refresh when load my page...

Answer (score 0):

done...thanks for all + @jasper too..i got other solution...i m last time use refresh for get parameter in URL ( using GET ) ..but 1 day find them still can'not

for now im use other solution ( POST ) method

this my code

in php

```
<a href="#product?id=<?php echo $row_getd['id_product']; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333;" onclick="onBodyLoad1(<?php echo $row_getd['id_product'];?>);">
```

in .js

```
  var serviceURL = "http://localhost/m/";
    //var serviceURL = "http://kimpuler.com";

function onBodyLoad1(idku){

    var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
    var product = serviceURL+'contentproduct.php?id='+id;
    $("#contentproduct").load(product,{'id':idku}, function(){
    location.reload;
    });
```

hope can help for other people when same problem like me..

thanks @jasper also..you really great person...your code give me inspiration and will use in future...

Regard
jk